# Why is the sub-nav positioning off in IE7?

Tags: css

I am experiencing a discrepancy between the views of the main navigation in IE7 versus all other browsers in [this website](http://www.rouviere.com/_test/)

The active state and the hover state should completely cover the black with the tan. The other problem is that the sub-navigation background "jumps" up about 3px when you mouse over the menu.

Here is the html:

```
<ul id="mainNav">
        <li><a class="selected" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            </span>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            </span>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="#">Home Remodels</a>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            </span>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="#">New Home Builds</a>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            </span>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            </span>
        <li><a href="#">Our Blog</a>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            </span>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="#">FAQ'S</a>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            </span>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And here is the CSS

```
ul#mainNav      { clear: both; width: 930px; height: 39px; margin: -5px 0 0 0; padding: 0; float: left; list-style-type: none; position: relative; background-color: #0d0600; font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; color: #fff; }
ul#mainNav li       { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul#mainNav li a         { padding: 12px 14px 12px 14px; display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }
ul#mainNav li a.selected,
ul#mainNav li a:hover             { background: #b5a37e url(../_images/bg_mainNav.jpg) repeat-x left top; }
ul#mainNav li span a:hover      { background-image: none; }
ul#mainNav span         { float: left; display: none; padding-top: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 10; left: 0; top: 39px; width: 930px; background-color: #b5a37e; color: #fff; text-transform: none; }
ul#mainNav li:hover span        { display: block; }
ul#mainNav li span a                { display: inline; padding: 10px 14px 10px 14px; }
ul#mainNav li span a:hover, 
ul#mainNav li span a.selected   { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one showed up so I kept at it and found my own solution:

I just needed to increase the padding:

```
ul#mainNav li a { padding: 12px 14px 18px 14px; }
ul#mainNav span { padding-top: 10px; top: 45px; }
```